# Application working when deployed on DB Server but when deploy on other working slow

Tags: sql-server

We have a MVC web Application which is working fine when we deploy on Same Data Base server. But when we separate Data Base and Application Servers application performance becomes very slow. Bellow are the details of OS and communication matrix.

- DB server: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installed on windows server 2012
- r2 Application Server: Two Application servers windows 2012 r2 Load
  Balancing enabled by F5.

I also want to mention here the same application was working perfectly with SQL server 2008 r2. 
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more details.

What about network between these servers? Are both machines in same datacenter? For example try to ping the databaseserver from applicationserver. What are the results of this ping?

UPDATE

OK. The thing I should do first is looking from database perspective so you can see where the problem is.  Do you know how the perform a trace with SQL Server Profiler? try to execute a trace when you are using the application.  Also try to be the only one using this application, so you're trace is easy to understand. You need to check if query's are executed fast.

You can also check wait statistics:

```
WITH Waits AS
(SELECT wait_type, wait_time_ms / 1000. AS wait_time_s,
100. * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER() AS pct,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC) AS rn
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE wait_type NOT IN ('CLR_SEMAPHORE','LAZYWRITER_SLEEP','RESOURCE_QUEUE','SLEEP_TASK'
,'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK','SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH','WAITFOR', 'LOGMGR_QUEUE','CHECKPOINT_QUEUE'
,'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH','XE_TIMER_EVENT','BROKER_TO_FLUSH','BROKER_TASK_STOP','CLR_MANUAL_EVENT'
,'CLR_AUTO_EVENT','DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE', 'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT'
,'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT', 'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN', 'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP'))
SELECT W1.wait_type,
CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
CAST(W1.pct AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS pct,
CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS running_pct
FROM Waits AS W1
INNER JOIN Waits AS W2
ON W2.rn <= W1.rn
GROUP BY W1.rn, W1.wait_type, W1.wait_time_s, W1.pct
HAVING SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 99 OPTION (RECOMPILE); -- percentage threshold
GO
```

Also a good idea to reset these statistics because these measures are summed from last SQL Server restart. You can restart these statistics:

```
DBCC SQLPERF('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR);
```

Comment: Yes Both machines are on same network and in same datacenter. Yes we can ping and ping is constant without any delay.

Comment: Yes Actually we already tested the Db server and also tested my Microsoft and its fine. I think the issue is only with the network between Db server and application server when they are seprate